# Testing Django with MongoDB(Djongo)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, testing, djongo

I'm looking for a way to test my Django app that works with MongoDB using Djongo.

I found [Django Test Addons](https://pythonhosted.org/django-test-addons/) library but as I understood, it only works with mongoengine. Is there any manner to make it work with Djongo or do you know another similar library that I can use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just run my django tests with own config:

```
manage.py test --settings=myproject.settings.unit_tests
```

In my unit test config, I just import my base settings, and then change database name. This seems to work fine.

```
from .base import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'test_myproject',
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'myproject-mongodb',
            'username': 'supermongo',
            'password': 'supersecret',        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what was the pymongo version in your project? I'm stuck with the same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978645/testing-drf-project-with-a-mongodb

Comment: @MikeDHovhannisyan Sorry, I don`t remember and I cancelled using djongo.

Comment: So you switched to a sql database?

Comment: @MikeDHovhannisyan Yes, postgres like always. Best choice for django, if you do not have really important reasons to use another db.