# Testing DRF project with a MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework, djongo

I have the following DB configuration in a DRF project.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'sauftrag_dev',
        'CLIENT': {
           'host': os.environ[DB_HOST],
        }
    }
}
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase'
    }
```

When running tests Django uses sqlite3 db, but I need to test in mongoDB. When I use mongoDB instance for testing I get an error. Here are the logs:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
This version of djongo does not support "NULL, NOT NULL column validation check" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using CONSTRAINT" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "COLUMN DROP NOT NULL " fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "DROP CASCADE" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 894, in _alter
    query.execute()
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 533, in _drop_column
    self.db[self.left_table].update(
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 3213, in __call__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'update' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
                  ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 885, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

    Keyword: None
    Sub SQL: None
    FAILED SQL: ALTER TABLE "django_content_type" DROP COLUMN "name" CASCADE
    Params: ()
    Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 725, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 643, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 179, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 74, in create_test_db
    call_command(
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 170, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 559, in remove_field
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/sauftrag/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/root/Desktop/my_project/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

The error basically says that the current version of djongo does not support certain features such as NULL/NOT NULL column validation, schema validation using CONSTRAINT, COLUMN DROP NOT NULL and DROP CASCADE but I'm using the latest version of djongo (1.3.6)

This is a follow up question to [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977463/how-to-set-up-test-db-settings-in-a-drf-project)